# How is the IOTA project now? Can we use it for a real project?

Tags: iota-network, development

Could you please tell me how the iota project is now?

I've read some good research papers and interesting proof of concepts, but it also seems some initiatives, like the ecosystem, are no more.

So if we're looking to do an energy finance project with blockchain, can we use iota?  Is it ready for production use?  Is there any developer or support community out there for it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

IOTA in it's current state should be considered as a work in progress protocol. It can technically be used right now, but I'd advice you to use it for Proof of Concepts only at this point, at least until Coordicide has rolled out. If you want to use it for a production platform right now be prepared to do changes later on since some things will change leading up to Coordicide.

I'm part of the, currently 7 man strong, ecosystem team so it's absolutely still there. The Ecosystem Development Fund is still active as well and undergoing a transformation, so if you want to do a proposal for that or want to apply to one of our [Request for Proposals](https://blog.iota.org/introducing-rfps-grant-updates-new-edf-management-efb4688818d4) , please do.

If you want to build a Energy/Finance PoC feel free to do so, but keep in mind IOTA is not in its final production-ready form yet. It is however good to have something ready for when we are. There's a great 27k man strong Discord server where a lot of people, including most people from the IOTA Foundation, can help you out if you are looking for assistance. You can join us on https://discord.iota.org.

Comment: Thanks!  That is very helpful.